# Why div and nav elements doesn't get horizentally center aligned with inline-block position

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to create a menu, although I may end up in implementing the design I would like to know why with the following code the div and two nav elements doesn't get centered and adding or removing one of them changes the position of other ones. I also made margins and padding of every element to 0 but it doesn't work. When I add a ul tag in nav tag a 1px margin at top appears and I can't handle it to make the whole nav and its inside elements vertically centered and in one line with outside elements
Here's the code

```css
/* top-bar brand */

.top-bar > .brand{
  width: 180px;
  color: var(--white);
}

.top-bar > .brand p{
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.top-bar li{
  display: inline-block;
}

.top-bar li a{
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* top-bar site-menu*/
.top-bar .site-menu{
  width: 370px;
  background-color: var(--white);
}

.top-bar .site-menu li a{
  color: var(--gray1);
}
```

```html
<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="brand">
    <p>Blog <strong>Template</strong></p>
  </div>

  <nav class="top-menu site-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">Cooperation</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!-- <nav class="top-menu categories-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Nature</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">People</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">Trips</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">Animals</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">Fashion</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">Tech</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">...</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav> -->
</div>
```

Comment: have u tried to set margin: 0 auto to the div and nav? and please don't use certain width if not necessary and yours is not the case

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could include a little sketch of what you would want it to look like.

Comment: Thank @Alopwer and yes I did these stuff and I just want to know why? I mean I can achieve the desired design but when the elements are inline-block why they should have unnecessary margins and when I put everything to 0 why it shouldn't come up and fill the 1px gap.

Comment: Thank you @FrancisRubio yes you're totally right and I've forgot to attach some shots.